# How to adjust bottom sheet dialog when the keyboard shows up

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want to achieve a similar effect as this application:

Without a keyboard:

[image]

with a keyboard:

[image]

my code looks like this:

recovery_password_dialog.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Odzyskiwanie hasła"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Wpisz swój email, a my wyślemy wiadomość w celu zresetowania hasła"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView6"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:counterMaxLength="64"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/mail_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invalidEmailText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invalid_email"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounding_rect"
        android:text="@string/send_email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/invalidEmailText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

LoginFragment.java

```java
var recoverPasswordButton = binding.recoverPassword;
recoverPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext());
    var bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
    var sheetBinding = RecoveryPasswordDialogBinding.inflate(inflater);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetBinding.getRoot());
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
});
```

just a simple code that only shows a dialog window without any widgets functionalities yet.

result:
[image]
[image]

I don't care about the theme right now. Colors don't matter. What matters is that the button hides under the keyboard which is not what I want. I've read that `windowSoftInputMode` may help with this, but my default setup has it already configured: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`. There was also written that ScrollView may help, but it actually doesn't change anything.

Any ideas on how can I achieve the second screenshot effect?

**EDIT** with scrollview

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/password_recovery"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Wpisz swój email, a my wyślemy wiadomość w celu zresetowania hasła"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView6"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:counterMaxLength="64"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/mail_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invalidEmailText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/invalid_email"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_input_layout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendEmail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounding_rect"
            android:text="@string/send_email"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/invalidEmailText"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
If we are using `ConstraintLayout`, then the entire thing becomes simpler. Consider the following example, no matter how much content there is, `pane2` will always show up at the bottom, and even be raised on top of the appearing keyboard. This is because it was instructed to always be at the bottom. Also notice how `pane1` was all nested inside a `ScrollView` so that it can grow depending on screen height/ content etc. Basically, we just separated the information providing panel and submission panels. Hope this solves it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/pane1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pane2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="top">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter something:"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pane2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pane1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SUBMIT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*----------------------------------------------------------------*

The issue is handled by adding `android:isScrollContainer="true"` to the immediate layout in quesiton for target layout xml file.

Update: What you need to do is declare a scrollview and put all the children inside. scrollview doesn't allow that so you'll need to encase all them within a linearlayout. then add the property `android:isScrollContainer` in your **Scrollview** tag and set its value to `true`. remember, *non-direct* children of the constaint view should not have constraint attributes. only direct children has them. so once your textviews are inside the scrollview, only the scrollview should have the constraint properties, and they should no longer be there on your textviews as they would be **inside** the scrollview and not **directly** inside the main constraintlayout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width....
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    constraint-props....>
    <LinearLayout
        .....
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ... child
        ... child
        ... child
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: provided that the layout is a ```ScrollView```.

Comment: I don't know maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it didn't help. I've just edited the question to show how the scrollview looks in my case. Maybe you'll spot something that'd help me.

Comment: so, constraint layout should almost always be parent as it is all-encapsulating. so in your layout, make your scrollview the immediate child of your constraint layout

Comment: Nah, it still does not work. I don't know maybe the `BottomSheetDialog` class does not support it, because my main fragment layout also uses a `ScrollView` and it works, but somehow for the `BottomSheetDialog` it does not. I did exactly as you've shown. Constraint Layout -> ScrollView (with constraints properties) -> Linear Layout -> Widgets (of course without constraints properties, because they're in a linear layout). Still the same